# Xamarin to .Net MAUi conversion

Tags: xamarin.forms, maui

I have a custom ListView control and custom scrollbar with it's renderer in .Net MAUI. As I am reusing the same renderer in MAUI.
Below is the custom Datagrid.xaml UI structure

```
    <Grid><AbsoluteLayout Grid.Row="1">
    <ScrollView x:Name="Sv" Orientation="Horizontal" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1">
        <helpers:DataGridListView x:Name="ListView"></helpers:DataGridListView>
    </ScrollView>
    <helpers:DataGridVertScrollBar IsVisible="{Binding EnableCustomScroll}" HorizontalOptions="End" x:Name="ssv" HeightRequest="200" WidthRequest="8" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="HeightProportional,YProportional,XProportional"
             AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,1,8,1"></helpers:DataGridVertScrollBar>
</AbsoluteLayout>
<ContentView x:Name="NoDataViewElement" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" VerticalOptions="Center" IsVisible="False"/>
```

DataGrid.xaml.cs

```
    internal IList<DataGridRowModel> InternalItems
{
    get => _internalItems;
    set
    {
        _internalItems = value;

        //if(_internalItems == null || !_internalItems.Any()) return;

        if (IsSortable && SortedColumnIndex != null)
            SortItems(SortedColumnIndex);
        else
        {
            ListView.ItemsSource = _internalItems;
        }
        if (EnableCustomScroll)
        {
            var h = (ListView.RowHeight * (_internalItems.Count)) * 1.0;
            if (h == 0)
            {
                ssv.UpdateHeight(1);
            }
            else
            {
                double x = ssv.Height / h;
                if (x > 1) x = 1;
                ssv.UpdateHeight(x);
            }
        }
```

Helper class as below

```
public class DataGridVertScrollBar : AbsoluteLayout
 {
     BoxView thumb;
     double height;

     public DataGridVertScrollBar()
     {
         HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End;
         BackgroundColor = Color.FromRgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
         thumb = new BoxView { WidthRequest = 8, HeightRequest = 40, BackgroundColor = Color.FromRgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center };
         Children.Add(thumb);
         AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(thumb, new Rect(1.1, 1, 1, 1));
         AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(thumb, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.HeightProportional | AbsoluteLayoutFlags.WidthProportional);
     }

     public void UpdateHeight(double val)
     {
         IsVisible = val != 1;

         height = val;
         AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(thumb, new Rect(0, 0, 1, height));
     }

     public void Move(double y)
     {
         if (y > Height) y = Height;
         AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(thumb, new Rect(0, y, 1, height));
     }
 }
```

My problem is ssv.Height value is coming -1 even when _internalItems have data.
In old xamarin application it is working fine, When _internalItems.Count>0 ssv.Height is 215 instead of -1.

I don't know why scrollbar template is not rendering initially.

Please help I am new to MAUI.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the code you provided and found that the `ssv.Height` still be -1 in the MAUI project, the Height can not be found in the MAUI project.

You can try to use Task and make the method run after the layout has been loaded.

```
 Task task = Task.Run(() =>
 {
     var h = (listView.RowHeight * (9)) * 1.0;
     if (h == 0)
     {
         ssv.UpdateHeight(1);
     }
     else
     {
         double x = ssv.Height / h;
         if (x > 1) x = 1;
         ssv.UpdateHeight(x);
     }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Height property is inside Microsoft.Maui.Controls VisualElement class. 


/// <summary>
/// Gets the current rendered height of this element. This is a read-only bindable property.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>The height of an element is set during layout.</remarks>
public double Height
{
 get { return _mockHeight == -1 ? (double)GetValue(HeightProperty) : _mockHeight; }
 private set { SetValue(HeightPropertyKey, value); }
}

And Height is auto-populate based on control rendering

Comment: I found the reason why the height cannot be got. The layout in MAUI had not been loaded before you use the method to get the ssv.height. I tried to use the Task make the method run after the layout loaded. You can check my answer.

Comment: Thanks, tried your solution it is still showing -1.  
public DataGrid()
 {
     InitializeComponent();
     InternalItems = new List<DataGridRowModel>();
I am calling this function after InitializeComponent(). Even after not working

Comment: You can make the method run after the layout has been loaded. Like put it in the button and click the button to get the data. It will get the height.

Comment: yes can try but I don't know why it is working fine in xamarin